# Featherlight.js - how to update properties on already open featherlight iframe

Tags: javascript, featherlight.js

I am opening a new featherlight iframe like this:

```
$.featherlight({
    iframe:href,
    iframeWidth:$(window).width(),
    iframeHeight:$(window).height(),
    openSpeed:0,
    beforeClose:myBeforeCloseCallback
});
```

How can I later update the properties of the open featherlight window (such as `beforeClose`) and load a new URL?  I'm guessing I start with `$.featherlight.current();`, but what next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a good feature to add. There's no such feature right now though.

You could do `$.featherlight.current().setContent($('<b>example</b>'))`, for example.

Here's how [we do it in the gallery](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/blob/master/src/featherlight.gallery.js#L130-L147)

Simplest code that would work would look like: (not tested)

```
var fl = $.featherlight.current();
fl.iframe = "new url";
var $newContent = ;
$.when(fl.getContent(), function($content) {
  fl.setContent($content)
});
```

Feel free to open an issue, or even better a PR...